# Time complexity of a recursive algorithm with nested iterative function?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

a)

```
void f(n){
  if(n<=1) return;
    else{
      g(n); //g(n) is O(N^2).
      f(n/2);
      f(n/2);
    } 
}
```

b)

```
void f(n){
  if(n<=1) return;
    else{
      g(n); //g(n) is O(N).
      f(n-1);
      f(n-1);
    } 
}
```

c)

```
void f(n){
  if(n<=1) return;
    else{
      g(n); //g(n) is O(N^2).
      f(n-1);
      f(n-1);
    } 
}
```

How do I count the O(n) complexity of the above two code snippet?

a) I got the answer O(n^2), because each f(n) calls itself twice recursively. And since the depth of the tree is LogN (n/2), the overall complexity is O(n^2), do i disregard the g(n) method since it is N^2 as well?

b) Since the depth of the tree is N, and each f(n) calls itself twice recursively. And since each level needs to perform g(n) operation N times, I got the answer O(N.2^(N)).

c) Same as b) but g(n) is performed N^2 time - hence O(N^2.2^(N)).

Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) The recursive equation is as bellow.

[image]

If you expand the recursion we have:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

So we want to calculate last equation which is equal to:

[image]

Since the last part of above equation is a geometric serie we have:

[image]

So the recursion is [image].

b) The approach is same as before.

[image]

which is equal to:

[image]

So the answer is [image]

c) Third part can solve with the same technique.

[image]

[image]

**PS:** Thanks to *Alexandre Dupriez* for his comment.

**PS:** For an **elegant** simplification of the summation read *Alexandre*'s comments bellow.

Comment: for b) and c), it seems to me that complexity is `O(2^n)` - the reason is in the second term of `T(n) = 2^n + n.sum(2^i)`, `n` cannot be factored as the sum are respectively `n + 2.(n - 1) + ... + 2^n` for (b) and `n^2 + 2.(n-1)^2 + ... + 2^n`.

Comment: @AlexandreDupriez Thanks for your correction, I missed the decreasing part of that part. I edited the answer. Please check it again.

Comment: Agreed with the result `theta(2^n)` - not sure how you get to the simplification of the sums? Anyway, I wouldn't bother too much about getting an exact expression for the partial sum - I'd just justify by the fact that `sum(2^i.(n-i)) = 2^n.sum((n-i)/2^(n-i)) = 2^n.sum(k/2^k)` and it happens the series of general term `k/2^k` converges to a finite number (let's call it `c`) and since the finite sum is increasing, `sum(k/2^k) <= c` so `2^n.sum(k/2^k) <= c.2^n` and since we can find a lower bound of the form `d.2^n` for another `d < c`, you get the `theta(2^n)`.

Comment: Same reasoning with the series `sum(k^2/2^k)` - and more generally with any integer `p`, `sum(k^p/2^k)` always converges to a finite number - so we can generalize the exercises above with `g(n)` having a complexity of the form `O(n^p)` for any given integer `p`.

Comment: We can also generalize further for any complexity `g(n)` such that the series `sum(g(n)/2^n)` is finite, which in particular gives us access to anything of the form `a1.n^p1.log(n)^q1 + a2.n^p2.log(n)^q2 + ...` for any `a1, a2, ...; p1, p2...; q1, q2...`, etc.

Comment: @AlexandreDupriez **Elegant** simplification. For exact calculation of equation we can split the summation to `sum(n*2^i) + sum(i*2^i)`. First part is geometric series and for second there is *Exponential terms* part in [summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation) page of wikipedia. Also [wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum_%7Bi+%3D+0%7D%5E%7Bn%7D%7B2%5Ei+*+(n+-+i)%7D) can compute it for us. I suggest in answer to every one read your comments. Thanks.

Comment: oh, I didn't know about wolframalpha - nice and powerful tool! Thanks